# How to install Ubuntu without an access to a CD drive or USB ports

Tags: system-installation

I'm using a Nextbook laptop, on which the usbs are broken, and it doesn't have a cd drive. I used a SD card with Ubuntu on it, I just dont know how to boot it up.

Any suggestions or help?

Comment: maybe you also have to reorder the boot-device-priority in the bios/efi...

Answer (score 0):

If the card slot is connected to that laptop via standard means (usb rail), then I'd say that it probably is possible with a properly (via Unetbootin) flashed card.

It is also possible (on some machines) to install os over the network. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/810314/install-os-over-network) is how.

If it is not possible on your's, then the only way to do this I can think of, is by getting the hard drive out of the chassis, connecting it to something else, and installing things the natural way.